# Why the splice function doesn't work properly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
    for (var i=0; i<str2.length; i++){
        if (str1.split('').indexOf(str2[i])>=0){
            str1.split('').splice(str1.split('').indexOf(str2[i]),1);
            console.log(str1)
        } else {return false};
    } return true
}

scramble('rkqodlw','world')
```

I have a question about the splice function, after running this code, the str1 doesn't change every time, and I really don't know where the problem is.

Comment: Please provide input, what the expected output would be , and what you get as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not apply `splice()` on `str1`. You are applying `splice()` on `str1.split('')`. To fix this assign `str1` to array in start of function and then use `splice()`

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values)

> All types except `objects` define immutable values (values, which are incapable of being changed). For example and unlike to C, **Strings are immutable**. We refer to values of these types as **primitive values**.

`str1.split('')` doesnot change the value of `str1` instead it `return` a new value which should stored in variable.

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
    str1 = str1.split('');
    for (var i=0; i<str2.length; i++){
        if (str1.indexOf(str2[i])>=0){
            str1.splice(str1.indexOf(str2[i]),1);
            console.log(str1.join(''))
        } else {return false};
    } return true
}

scramble('rkqodlw','world')
```

**Easier Way**:

You can do that easier way using `filter()` and `includes()`

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
     return str1.split('').filter(x => !str2.includes(x))
}
console.log(scramble('rkqodlw','world'))
```

Answer (score 1):

str1.split('') return new Array of string and str1 is NOT changed.

Answer (score 0):

`str1.split('')` returns a new array. Calling `splice` on this array will modify that array and not `str1`.

Splice on an array will modify the array:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.splice(2);
arr;  // [1, 2]
```

But not the string the array was constructed from.

```
let str = '1 2 3';
let arr = str.split(' ');
arr.splice(2);
str; // ' 1 2 3'
arr; // ['1', '2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You are return same `str1` not with after spliced value.So you need to defined split before loop `spl`.

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  var spl =str1.split('');
  for (var i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    if (spl.indexOf(str2[i]) > -1) {
      spl.splice(spl.indexOf(str2[i]), 1);
      console.log(spl.join(''))
    } else {
      return false
    };
  }
  return true
}

scramble('rkqodlw', 'world')
```

**For simplified version**

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  str2.split('').forEach(a=> str1=str1.replace(a,''));
  return str1;
}

console.log(scramble('rkqodlw', 'world'))
```